# Arduino device type is not found at wso2 iot server's device enroll directory

Tags: wso2-iot

There is not found android at "device types" section when I browse (https://localhost:9443/devicemgt/device/enroll to enroll android device.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In order to Enable IOT Device types which is shipped with WSO2 IOT Server you need to install those plugins in to the server prior to the server startup.

To enable the plugins please follow the steps below,

- Stop the server.
- Execute the following commands,

> ```
> cd <IoTS_HOME>/plugins
> mvn clean install -f plugins-deployer.xml
> ```

- Then start the servers again.

Now you can see the rest of the iot device types listed under the enroll device page.